# Error with getting TextBox data and manipulating it - CLOSED -

Tags: lua, roblox

Before I start, I will say that *there are no error messages in the console, of any type*. Anyway, I have been trying to make a user tools game where a player can look at their avatar, look like them, etc. It used to work well in the default Roblox chat, but since that gets moderated, I made a "chat bar" for my game. However, now only one of these functions works (`AvatarInspectMenu` with a `UserId`, and not a username). Take a look for yourself:

```lua
-- client script
local Players=game:GetService("Players")
local Player=Players.LocalPlayer
local StarterGui=game:GetService("StarterGui")
local GuiService=game:GetService("GuiService")
local Rep=game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
repeat wait(0.1) until Player.Character
local h=Player.Character:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
StarterGui:SetCore("TopbarEnabled",false)
local ChatBar=Player.PlayerGui:WaitForChild("ScreenGui").Frame.BoxFrame.Frame.ChatBar
GuiService:SetInspectMenuEnabled(false)
local CS=game:GetService("ContextActionService")
CS:BindAction("Chat Focus",function()
    ChatBar:CaptureFocus()
end,false,Enum.KeyCode.Slash)
function ID(str)
    if tonumber(str)~=nil then
        return tonumber(str)
    else
        return Rep.Idify:InvokeServer(str)
    end
end
ChatBar.FocusLost:Connect(function(entr)
    if not entr then return end
    ChatBar:ReleaseFocus(true)
    local m=ChatBar.Text
    ChatBar.Text=""
    if m=="!reset" then
        Rep.Desc:InvokeServer(Player.UserId)
    end
    if h.Sit then
        if #string.split(m," ")==1 then
            local id=ID(m)
            if h.SeatPart.Name=="AvatarInspectMenu" then
                GuiService:InspectPlayerFromUserId(id)
            end
            if h.SeatPart.Name=="Become" then
                local Desc=Rep.Desc:InvokeServer(id)
                h.Sit=false
            end
            if h.SeatPart.Name=="Tep" then
                local P,J=Rep.Join:InvokeServer(id)
                if not (P and J) then return end
                game:GetService("TeleportService"):TeleportToPlaceInstance(P,J,Player)
            end
        end
    end
end)

-- server-side script
local cache={}
local rep=game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
rep.Idify.OnServerInvoke=function(_,n)
    if cache[n] then return cache[n] end
    local player=game.Players:FindFirstChild(n)
    if player then
        cache[n]=player.UserId
        return player.UserId
    end
    local id
    pcall(function ()
        id=game.Players:GetUserIdFromNameAsync(n)
    end)
    if not id then return 156 end
    cache[n]=id
    return id
end
local dcs={}
rep.Desc.OnServerInvoke=function(p,n)
    if not dcs[n] then
        pcall(function()
            dcs[n]=game:GetService("Players"):GetHumanoidDescriptionFromUserId(n)
        end)
    end
    p.Character.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame=CFrame.new(0,10,0)
    if not dcs[n] then
        p.Character.Humanoid:ApplyDescription(game:GetService("Players"):GetHumanoidDescriptionFromUserId(156))
        return false
    else
        p.Character.Humanoid:ApplyDescription(dcs[n])
        return true
    end
end
rep.Join.OnServerInvoke=function(_,n)
    local id,jb=nil
    pcall(function()
        id,jb=game:GetService("TeleportService"):GetPlayerPlaceInstanceAsync(n)
    end)
    if id and jb then return id, jb else return nil end
end
```

I've looked through the code, but I can't seem to find any problems (Except, of course, that there is no error message while trying to attempt a teleport in Studio). Help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: This code is fully functional. No more help is needed! :D

Comment: I tested AvatarInspectMenu and Become and it works for me with those two scripts. The only thing I had to do is add a missing "end" to the end.

Comment: Where did you add the `end`? I can't seem to find where.

Comment: at the end ;) -- its missing from the last if statement in the server script.

Comment: @Night94 Oh! I didn't notice :) However, it still doesn't work. :c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no error then it works, maybe you missed something out which wasn't called, try adding some prints within functions to see if it prints.